# How Do I Ensure My HTTP API Gateway Rejects Incorrectly Formatted JSON Per Endpoint In The CDK?

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, response, aws-cdk, api-gateway

**Problem**

API Gateway is currently accepting all JSON that is sent to it, returning a `200` response. This is not the preferred use case, and I'd like to create a per-endpoint opinion of what fields are required. Maybe, using Typescript `Interface` in the invoked lambda to throw a `500` response back.

Idea / Steps:

1. Data is sent into the API Gateway endpoint "/example"
2. The JSON is received by the invoked Lambda
3. The lambda uses TypeScript `Interface`
4. The `JSON` is found to be incorrectly formatted
5. API Gateway sends the correct response code that informs the sender that required fields in the JSON have not been received OR are incorrect (e.g. number not string).

**Note:** I am building all resources in the CDK.

Comment: Did you already look into the option to integrate JSON schemas into the API Gateway? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/model-api-gateway/

Comment: This is what I am looking for, absolutely. Just need ot know how to do it per endpoint in the cdk

Comment: Are you using [proxy or non-proxy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-integrations.html) Lambda integration?

Comment: It looks like proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript can't perform validations (or anything else) at run-time: your NodeJS Lambda handler doesn't speak types.  It runs the compiled Javascript.

If you want help with run-time JSON input validation, consider the popular [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/about.html#about),  *"a declarative language that allows you to annotate and validate JSON documents."*  A JSON Schema is similar to a TS interface.  It is itself expressed as a JSON document.

How you implement API Gateway request validation with JSON Schema is different for the [two types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-integrations.html) of Lambda integration.  The suggestions made by @Maurice and @JimsonJames use JSONSchema to define a request Model resource.  You can do this with the CDK, but only when using the [non-proxy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-lambda-non-proxy-integration.html) integration.

You are using the [Lambda Proxy Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html).  As such, your Lambda function must perform the validations itself.  Define a JSON Schema document representing the expected shape and types.  Use a validator package like [ajv](https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv) (92 million weekly downloads) in your Lambda handler to validate the incoming event against that schema.  In case of validation failure, `ajv` can produce the [error feedback](https://ajv.js.org/api.html#validation-errors) you're looking for.

```js
// my-handler.ts

const ajv = new Ajv()
const validate = ajv.compile<MyData>(schema)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. for example, if you are using SAM see the code snippet below (you can do the same with CDK if you go that route).

Here you can specify your `passthroughBehavior` to `never`, to block any invalid input.

Also, you can specify `x-amazon-apigateway-request-validators` to validate all your request headers and body.

Take a look at the documentation on how to do basic request validation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-validation-set-up.html)

```
  MyServerlessApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      # Use DefinitionBody for swagger file so that we can use CloudFormation intrinsic functions within the swagger file
      DefinitionBody:
        "Fn::Transform":
          Name: "AWS::Include"
          Parameters:
            Location: "../../swagger/api.yaml"
      StageName: v1
      EndpointConfiguration: REGIONAL
      TracingEnabled: true # Enable AWS X-Ray to help debug API requests
      MethodSettings:
        - ResourcePath: "/*"
          HttpMethod: "*"
          # Disable data trace in production to avoid logging customer sensitive information from requests and responses
          DataTraceEnabled: true
          LoggingLevel: INFO
          MetricsEnabled: true
          ThrottlingRateLimit: 300
          ThrottlingBurstLimit: 350
      AccessLogSetting:
        DestinationArn: !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:slsapi1grp"
        Format: '$context.identity.sourceIp $context.authorizer.claims.sub [$context.requestTime] "$context.httpMethod $context.resourcePath $context.protocol" $context.status $context.requestId $context.awsEndpointRequestId $context.xrayTraceId $context.responseLatency $context.integrationLatency "$context.error.message"'
      OpenApiVersion: "3.0.0"
      Cors:
        AllowOrigin: "'*'"
        AllowHeaders: "'authorization, content-type'"
```

api.yaml
A snippet from swagger schema

```
openapi: 3.0.0

info:
  title:
    Fn::Sub: validate-request
  description: Validation Snippet
  contact:
    email: email@local
  version: 1.0.0

# Enable request validator. 
# See doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-validation-sample-api-swagger.html
x-amazon-apigateway-request-validators:
  "All":
    validateRequestBody: true
    validateRequestParameters: true
  "ValidateHeaderOnly":
    validateRequestBody: false
    validateRequestParameters: true
  "ValidateBodyOnly":
    validateRequestBody: true
    validateRequestParameters: false
x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator: "All" # Validate Header and Body

x-amazon-apigateway-gateway-responses:
  # Provide more detailed error message for bad request body errors. 
  # See doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-gateway-responses.html
  BAD_REQUEST_BODY:
    responseTemplates:
      application/json: '{"errorCode": "BadRequestBody", "message": "$context.error.validationErrorString"}'
    responseParameters:
      gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
  DEFAULT_4XX:
    responseParameters:
      gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
  DEFAULT_5XX:
    responseParameters:
      gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
paths:
  /api:
    post:
      operationId: Create
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/CreateInput"
        required: true
      responses:
        "201":
          description: "Create"
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Details"
        "400":
          description: "Bad Request Exception"
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/BadRequestException"
        "401":
          description: "Unauthorized Exception"
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/UnauthorizedException"
        "409":
          description: "Conflict Exception"
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/ConflictException"
        "429":
          description: "Too Many Requests Exception"
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/TooManyRequestsException"
        "500":
          description: "Internal Server Error"
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/InternalServerErrorException"
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri:
          Fn::Sub: arn:${AWS::Partition}:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${MyServerlessApi.Arn}:live/invocations
        httpMethod: POST
        type: aws_proxy
        passthroughBehavior: never # do not send incorrectly formatted input
      security:
        - tokenAuthorizer: []
```

Comment: Just need to know how to do it in the CDK now.

Comment: may be https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.PassthroughBehavior.html of help.